# Reading templates from a folder via DocuSign API REST V2

Tags: php, rest, templates, docusignapi

I need to read templates from my dev account - I'm using the /templates REST API V2 (page 192 in the API guide - http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf)

sending folder as "Admissions", includeSubFolders as true (Yes, I have a subfolder called Admissions and there is a template in there)

the error I'm getting back from the API is: 
errorCode:INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER
message:The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Template definition must    include an 'envelopeTemplateDefinition' section.

The API specs for parms are only folder and includeSubFolders... says nothing about envelopeTemplateDefinition - I'm only trying to read a list of templates so I can retrieve said Template information

has anybody else had this issue ? - what's the fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your Request is using the verb **GET**. For example, if the folder structure within my DocuSign account looks like this:

[image: DocuSign UI - Template Folder Structure]

Then the request to get all templates within the ***TF Templates*** folder would be:

```
GET https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/templates?Folder=TF%20Templates&includeSubFolders=true
```

Based on the error you're getting, I'd suspect that you're (incorrectly) using the verb **POST** instead of using the verb **GET**. **POST** is used when you want to Create a new template (in which case **envelopeTemplateDefinition** is required).

Comment: That was the issue! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help!  When you have a moment, can you please mark this as an accepted answer, so that others can benefit from the information in the future? Thanks!